# How to remove Certbot completely ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, certbot

I ran this command `sudo dpkg -l *certbot*` and I got this certbot and the version number listed in the terminal:

[image]

Next I ran this 2 commands `sudo apt-get remove certbot` and `sudo apt autoremove` and I though the certbot would be removed. But when I ran again `sudo dpkg -l *certbot*`, it still not removed and it still show the same as the image above.

How do I completely remove certbot? Thanks

Comment: Should be as simply as using [sudo certbot delete](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1142409/how-to-completely-remove-certbot-from-ubuntu#:~:text=Remove%20Certbot%20from%20Ubuntu%201%20Remove%20Certbot.%20sudo,sudo%20service%20apache2%20restart.%20If%20...%20See%20More.)

Comment: Fwiw, just to explain the commands & the resulting output: "remove" gets rid of the program, but not the configuration files (hence "rc"); use "purge" to also delete config files. The packages are uninstalled (ie, removed), but the system still knows they were once installed but nothing else (hence, "un", or "unknown"). Using "purge" and then "clean" will rid the system of all memory of the packages, as far as dpkg/apt is concerned. https://askubuntu.com/questions/18804/what-do-the-various-dpkg-flags-like-ii-rc-mean

Answer (score 2):

just run the following command after it

```
sudo apt purge certbot
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The following command only removes the package itself so you cannot run it anymore:

```
apt remove certbot
```

But configuration files are still remained at `/etc/`

If you intend to remove all existing files, the run:

```
apt purge certbot
```